# Do the effect of the quantum mechanics varies, on the CMB

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmic-microwave-background

Let's take for a example the nature of electrons, when conducting the double slit experiment. If I were to conduct the experiment outside the CMB, if possible, would I see the same result?

Comment: CMB is just radio waves. You can shield from them easily with metal walls. Why do you think CMB would affect electrons in a double slit experiment?

Comment: I'm talking about huge amounts of radio waves.

Comment: What "huge amounts"? CMB is very weak.

Comment: gravity is also a weak force, but when theres a lot of its strong enough to collapse a star and affect the way particles interact, for example fusion. that has to be a alteration in quantum mechanics.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, such as what you mean by CMB and why it is strong. Perhaps you are referring to the time of the early universe, I am not sure, but your question is unclear. Please don't just reply with comments, but edit your question to make it perfectly clear for everyone to see what you are talking about.

Comment: This is basically asking whether a lightbulb in the room interferes with an expriment in a box that is sealed off from light.

Answer (score 0):

Many experiments in quantum mechanics involve [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle#Quantum_superposition). Probably the most important current example is in the construction of quantum computers where the qubits have to be maintained in a superposition of states.

The big enemy for the experimenter is [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) because this destroys the superposition and messes up our experiments. I've linked the Wikipedia article on decoherence, but that is probably a bit technical for the non quantum theory expert. Suffice to say that in decoherence the quantum system interacts with its environment and that interaction causes the superposition to collapse.

You are quite correct that the CMB can interact with experiments, and that interaction can cause decoherence and spoil the experiment. But as mentioned in a comment the CMB is just microwave radiation and is easily screened out. And in any case the amplitude of the CMB is very small so it doesn't have a very big effect on most experiments. The radio waves from your local radio station carry many times more energy than the CMB so it's the local radio station that would worry the experimenter most, not the CMB.